# Change a Node Reference field value with VBO

Tags: 7, rules, views

I'm having trouble setting a Node Reference field using [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). If I select Integer as the parameter type it doesn't change the field value, and if I set it to Node Reference it has a "Data selector *" field for the input and no value seems to satisfy it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should select full node as a parameter. If you have only nid, you can load node just in rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok what worked out was having 2 parameters. One the node I'm altering, the other an integer field to input the node ID. Then I set up a "Fetch entity by id" action using the integer parameter. I use the entity variable provided by the fetch action to set the node reference field.